# C++ cons implementation - is there any way of making the constructor more readable?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have decided to make a basic `cons` implementation in C++, mainly to get the variadic template functionality without C++11, even though it is a lot more limited. My problem is: the constructor for the class is very unreadable, and it could get worse, depending on the amount of `cons` nesting in the template. This is because the constructor

```
cons< int, cons< int, cons<std::string> > > x(4, cons< int, cons<std::string> >(5, cons<std::string>("Hello")));
```

is quite a mouthful, and hard to read, so I would ideally like it to be

```
cons< int, cons< int, cons<std::string> > > x(4, 5, "Hello");
```

I may have gone wrong somewhere else, so feel free to correct me.

```
struct null_t
{
    null_t()
    {
    }

    operator int()
    {
        return NULL;
    }
};

template < typename _Ty1, typename _Ty2 = null_t > struct cons : public null_t
{
public:
    typedef _Ty1 _Ty1;
    typedef _Ty2 _Ty2;
    typedef cons<_Ty1, _Ty2> _Myt;

    cons()
        : var_x(), var_y()
    {
    }

    cons(const _Ty1 &_Var_x, const _Ty2 &_Var_y = null_t())
        : var_x(_Var_x), var_y(_Var_y)
    {
    }

    cons(const _Myt &_Rhs)
        : var_x(_Rhs.__var_x), var_y(_Rhs.var_y)
    {
    }

    template < typename _Ty3, typename _Ty4 > cons(const cons<_Ty3, _Ty4> &_Rhs)
        : var_x(_Rhs.var_x), var_y(_Rhs.var_y)
    {
    }

    _Myt &operator=(const _Myt &_Rhs)
    {
        var_x = _Rhs.var_x;
        var_y = _Rhs.var_y;
        return *this;
    }

    template < typename _Ty3, typename _Ty4 > _Myt &operator=(const cons<_Ty3, _Ty4> &_Rhs)
    {
        var_x = _Rhs.var_x;
        var_y = _Rhs.var_y;
        return *this;
    }

    _Ty1 &x()
    {
        return var_x;
    }

    _Ty2 &y()
    {
        return var_y;
    }

private:
    _Ty1 var_x;
    _Ty2 var_y;
};

int main()
{
    cons< int, cons< int, cons<std::string> > > x(4, cons< int, cons<std::string> >(5, cons<std::string>("Hello")));
    // Ideally cons< int, cons< int, cons<std::string> > > x(4, 5, "Hello");
    std::cout << x.x() << "\n";
    std::cout << x.y().x() << "\n";
    std::cout << x.y().y().x();
}
```

Comment: If you have working code that needs to be touched up, head over to Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Stack Overflow is for diagnosing and fixing broken code :-)

Comment: `typedef _Ty1 _Ty1;` what?

Comment: @Paranaix: completely makes sense in a template struct. You store the parameters inside the struct.

Answer (score 3):

You're in template land, so you can define constructors that won't even compile if they're used. Just decide on a limit, say 15 types (pseudo-tuple size). Then provide 15 constructors.

---

By the way, check out the **[type list](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-programmingtypelists-and-applica/184403813)** implementation in Andrei Alexandrescu's book "Modern C++ Design". If you don't have access to the book, you can (probably) also find it in the Loki library implementation. The book can be read as an introduction to essential aspects of Loki.

You might also check out the **[Boost tuple library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html)**. Maybe Boost supports your pre-C++11 compiler. Then chances are that Boost tuple is a superior solution, and at any rate, less work! ;-)